# Postman not getting installed

Tags: windows, api, installation, postman, project

I had downloaded postman for working on a project, it was working all fine but suddenly the application was not getting opened. I tried a few times and then reinstalled it. Now when I am trying to install the application it says, "There was an error while installing the application. Check the setup log for more information"
I have tried some solutions like deleting postman from localappdata and appdata caches, but nothing really helped. I am expecting it to get installed like normal and the application could work properly.
Could somebody help me with this problem?
Thank you!!

Comment: For what use cases do you use Postman for? If it's basic, there's a VSCode extension called Postcode that should do the job. If not, can u give us more details from the error log? I can't tell why Windows is upset from the current info.